# How do I add parameters to every ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, dojo

I'm developing a single page web-application using dojo and Java EE.

[simplified architecture](http://i55.tinypic.com/25ez7ec.png)

The client scripts exchange data with the backend using the dojox.data.JsonRestStore.

I want to atach the session-ID to every AJAX-Request.

I know that you can achieve this in JQuery by using ajax setup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
       //add parameters to request...
    }
});
```

Is there a way to setup dojo in a similar way?

Comment: Just add it to the URL string `&sid=xxxxx`, or in the "contents" property passed to dojo.xhrPost (which will show up as POST data).  Or, what's wrong with saving the session ID as a cookie on the browser machine?  Then it gets sent with every single request as a cookie.

Comment: Done that! made everything a lot easier :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an explicit hook to enable this unfortunately. One way to get around this (not tested, and it's not too pretty, but should do what you want):

```
define("my.xhr_fixer", ["dojo/xhr"], function(dojo){

(function() {
    dojo._xhr_orig = dojo.xhr;
    dojo.xhr = function(/*String*/ method, /*dojo.__XhrArgs*/ args, /*Boolean?*/ hasBody){
        args = args || {};
        args.content = args.content || {};

        args.content['sessionId'] = mySessionId;

        return dojo._xhr_orig.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();
});
```

Comment: Hey mrtom, thank you for the tip, but I switched to the cookie aproach as mentioned by Stephen. Anyway maybe this will be usefull in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the URL:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: "/yourcode?sessionId=" + sessionId;
});
```

Comment: Hi Diodeus, actually I'm searching for a Dojo only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can for analogy jQuery.beforeSend catch Dojo XHR message "send" and modify request parameters:

```
require([
    "dojo/request/notify",
    "dojo/cookie"
], function (notify, cookie) {
    notify("send", function (response, cancel) {
        response.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookie("csrftoken"));
    });
});
```